# fatest method to replace strlen in c++

Tags: c++, string

I have a c++ application which like to convert integer to string with leading zero very fast , in this test ,integer must be less than 100000000 , 100 million , compile it at g++ --std=c++11 -O3 test2.cpp -o test2.exe in g++ 4.8.5

the first test is using sprintf :

```
struct timeval  tv1,tv2;
char X1[16]={0} ;
int i1 = 9 ;
gettimeofday(&tv1,NULL) ;
for(int idx=0;idx<10000;idx++){
    sprintf(X1,"%08d",i1) ;
}
gettimeofday(&tv2,NULL) ;
printf("\n(%d)(%d)\n",tv1.tv_usec,tv2.tv_usec) ;
```

(900195)(900964) is printed , it cost 769 microseconds !!!

Then I try another test :

```
int MsgSeqNum = 9 ;
gettimeofday(&tv1,NULL) ;
for(int idx=0;idx<10000;idx++){ 
    char strSeqno[16]={0} ;
    fmt::ArrayWriter Seq(strSeqno) ;
    Seq.write("{:08d}",MsgSeqNum) ;
}
gettimeofday(&tv2,NULL) ;
printf("\n(%d)(%d)\n",tv1.tv_usec,tv2.tv_usec) ;
```

I use spdlog fmt::ArrayWriter , and it printf :
(321546)(321948) , it cost 402 microseconds .

then I try to use spdlog fmt::FormatInt to convert int to string :

```
char xtmp[16]={0} ;
char strSeqno[16]={0} ;
const char zero[] = "00000000000000" ;
int MsgSeqNum = 119 ;
gettimeofday(&tv1,NULL) ;
for(int idx=0;idx<10000;idx++){
    strcpy(xtmp,fmt::FormatInt(MsgSeqNum).c_str()) ;
    int ilen = strlen(xtmp) ;
    if( ilen >= 8 ){
        memcpy(strSeqno,xtmp,8) ;
    }else{
        memcpy(strSeqno,zero,8-ilen) ;
        memcpy(strSeqno+8-ilen,xtmp,ilen);
    }
}
gettimeofday(&tv2,NULL) ;
printf("\n(%d)(%d)\n",tv1.tv_usec,tv2.tv_usec) ;
```

in this test , (458194)(458344) is printed , it cost 150 microseconds .

then I try not to use strlen function and modify the source code :

```
char xtmp[16]={0} ;
char strSeqno[16]={0} ;
const char zero[] = "00000000000000" ;
int MsgSeqNum = 119 ;
gettimeofday(&tv1,NULL) ;
for(int idx=0;idx<10000;idx++){
    strcpy(xtmp,fmt::FormatInt(MsgSeqNum).c_str()) ;
    if( FixMsgSeqNum >= 10000000 ){
        memcpy(strSeqno,xtmp,8) ;
    }else if( FixMsgSeqNum >= 1000000 ){
        memcpy(strSeqno,zero,1) ;
        memcpy(strSeqno+1,xtmp,7) ;
    }else if( FixMsgSeqNum >= 100000 ){
        memcpy(strSeqno,zero,2) ;
        memcpy(strSeqno+2,xtmp,6) ;
    }else if( FixMsgSeqNum >= 10000 ){
        memcpy(strSeqno,zero,3) ;
        memcpy(strSeqno+3,xtmp,5) ;
    }else if( FixMsgSeqNum >= 1000 ){
        memcpy(strSeqno,zero,4) ;
        memcpy(strSeqno+4,xtmp,4) ;
    }else if( FixMsgSeqNum >= 100 ){
        memcpy(strSeqno,zero,5) ;
        memcpy(strSeqno+5,xtmp,3) ;
    }else if( FixMsgSeqNum >= 10 ){
        memcpy(strSeqno,zero,6) ;
        memcpy(strSeqno+6,xtmp,2) ;
    }else{
        memcpy(strSeqno,zero,7) ;
        memcpy(strSeqno+7,xtmp,1) ;
    }
}
gettimeofday(&tv2,NULL) ;
printf("\n(%d)(%d)\n",tv1.tv_usec,tv2.tv_usec) ;
```

and I get the  (479313)(479415)  , it cost 102 microseconds .

I like to know is there any method  to replace test3's strlen  and achieve
low latency like test4 ?!  look like strlen is not fast enough , but 
in test4  ,the if ...else  is quite not so clean .

Comment: Does `fmt::FormatInt(MsgSeqNum)` returns a std::string()? If so, just call it's `length()` method. Then no need to call `strlen()`.

Comment: You make `strlen` "really fast" by not using C strings at all. Store the length, then it is a single variable read to get the length, O(1). C++ `std::string` does this. `strlen` is an inherently O(n) operation.

Comment: In your case, the fastest conversion is probably to add `100000000` to every value, then throw away the leading digit. Leave `strlen` out of it completely.